# Flutter - How to use a class model

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning flutter coming from a react background. I want to use my model in another class.

This is my model

```
class User {
final String id;
final String userName;


User({
   this.id,
   this.userName,

});
}
```

On my Widget i want to use the properties of that model, so i can get some type safe.

```
class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final User _user; // I get an error on this line.

 final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

I get teh following error.

```
The value of the local variable '_user' isn't used.
Try removing the variable, or using it.dartunused_local_variable
The final variable '_user' must be initialized.
Try initializing the variable.
```

I'm a little bit confused how do you properly infer a model on class widget?

Answer (score 1):

Think about the model as a template - the way you are initializing the model - means there is nothing in it, **and** using the `final` variable means it will never change.

This causes an error, because the object is effectively `null`, and always will be.

If you initialize a variable with `final` you need give it data:

```
final User _user = User(id: 1, userName: test);
print(_user);
//Prints: Instance of User
```

Otherwise, don't use the `final` variable, and you can assign data to `_user` later"

```
User _user;
_user = User(id: 1, userName: test);
print(_user);
//Prints: Instance of User
```

Answer (score 0):

I will explain what your error means one by one.

Flutter will have a warning that you are creating a value that you aren't using.

```
The value of the local variable '_user' isn't used.
```

This is what they suggested:

```
Try removing the variable, or using it.dartunused_local_variable
```

These two error code is saying that your variable has to be instantiated:

```
The final variable '_user' must be initialized.
Try initializing the variable.
```

The solution to your problem is to instansiate User:

```
final User _user=User(id:"myId",userName:"myUserName");
```

Note that the final keyword is means that you are declaring a variable that will never have its value change.